# Why we should put space in scanf("% [^\n]")?

Tags: c, scanf, whitespace, format-specifiers

```
size_t n;
scanf("%d", &n);

char** arr;
arr = (char**)malloc(n * sizeof(char*));

for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    *(arr + i) = (char*)malloc(10000 * sizeof(char));
    scanf(" %[^\n]",*(arr+i));
    *(arr + i) = (char*)realloc(*(arr + i), strlen(*(arr + i)) + 1);
    puts(arr[i]);
}
```

When there is no space in `scanf("% [^\n]")` between `"` and `%` characters code is not working. Why we have to put space? What is the meaning of this space character?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>   scanf(" %[^\n]", *(arr+i));
> ```

The `" "` part of the format string skips over any and all leading whitespace, including newlines.

The  `"%[^\n]"` part of the format string reads all characters except for newlines, which means it reads to either (a) the end of line or (b) the EOF of the standard input stream. In case (a) the newline itself is left unread into the input stream.

Without the space, the next `scanf("%[^\n]", ...)` would then read the newline left behind by the previous `scanf` call as the first character, and would reject it because of the `^\n` exclusion, so it would fail to find a match for the `"%[^\n]"` format string.

*With* the space, the next `scanf(" %[^\n]", ...)` will first read and discard the newline (and any leading whitespace on the next line), then read the next string as expected.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  On a related note, it is always well advised to check the return value of `scanf`.

```
    if(scanf(" %[^\n]",*(arr+i)) != 1)  // nothing was matched
    {
        arr[i][0] = '\0';  // do not leave arr[i] uninitialized
    }
```